# What is code for the minimum capacity of a subpanel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am helping a customer finish a basement he started then couldn't finish. He and a friend installed a subpanel on a two pole 40 amp breaker using 8 AWG wire. There are four 15 amp breakers and three 20 amp breakers. The load will be 17 LED lights, roughly 25 receptacles.

There will be a theater room with projector and stereo equipment, a wet bar, bedroom and bathroom. I am a licensed journeyman and from what I see, the sub can't be smaller than 60 amps and I haven't ever encountered one under 60.

If I am going by load calculations, looks like 40 amp may be ok but is that code and where should I be looking in the code book?

Answer (score 4):

You're not required to feed 60A to a 60A-rated panel.  In fact I encourage you to use a 100, 125 or 200A panel, because those have more breaker spaces than a 60A.   If you want to feed any of them with a 40A breaker in the main panel, that's fine.

The breaker in the main panel **must** match the wiring from the main panel to the sub-panel.  Breakers protect wires.   This breaker protects that wire.  You are allowed to overprotect wires, but not underprotect.

240V/40A (9600VA) sounds ample for your basic man-cave improved basement, with earth shaking stereo and kilowatt gaming PC stuffed with multiple 980's.  I wish several other askers had that wiring for their man-cave!  It will be too little if the homeowner wants to put electric baseboard heating, wood shop (don't forget the dust collector) and/or electric dryer down there.

Answer (score 2):

The feeders and sub-panel need to be sized large enough to carry the calculated load. 3VA's per square foot plus the equipment. There are several sample load calculations in the Annexes in the back of the code book. Or pick up a copy of the text book [Code Calculations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193594102X) from the NJATC.

If you calculate it at 40 amps then that is your minimum. You can always go higher but not lower. Standard size sub-panels start at 60 amp capacity. As Ed Beal pointed out you can feed this panel with a 40 amp breaker and wire if you wish but that would necessitate an upgrade later when they want something else added. Best to just feed it with #6 and a 60 amp breaker to start with but since the wire is already installed then you could just leave it as long as it is big enough for the calculated load.

Sounds like you are on the right track anyway. Article 220 has the information you need.

Good luck!